# What type of bias is this?

Tags: bias, epidemiology

I have a longitudinal cohort study, with individuals that diagnosed with Disease A at "start", and they all developed Complication B at "end" in my study period (my study period covered 5 decades). Complication B develops very slowly from Disease A.

I wanted to show disease burden of Disease A and how it changed over time.

I summarised the total number of admissions in this population every decade, and the total years of follow up (patient-years) every decade and I divded this two to calculate the rate of admissions related to Disease A evey decade.

However, the follow-up time (patient-years) is much smaller in the last decade of the study period, because every patient in the last decade developed Complication B, whereas patients in the previous decades were a mix between those who developed Complication B (and therefore existed the follow-up) and those who continued follow-up to the next decade.

Therefore, I feel that my comparison of hospitalisation rates by decade is problematic because the  patient population in the last decade is quite different to patient population in previous decades  (ie, just before they developed Complication). What type of bias is this? Is it selection bias?? I feel that it's not really a censoring problem because no one is censored at the end of the study-period in my population, instead everybody exited follow up after an "event"?

Comment: If you are only looking at those who had disease A and later had complication B (never looking at those who had disease A but did not get complication B in the time period  of the study) then indeed you have selection bias.

Comment: But I have also read (without fully understood) about right truncation - and I am not sure if what I am describing here is more a right truncation problem?